# How to write a macro in exel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I need to cut the contents of the cell, to write a quotation mark, paste the contents of the cell to write another quotation mark then move to the next cell. Or anything else with the same result.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to provide you with the macro, or for guidance on how to do macros generally?

Answer (score 2):

Use Excel's native formatting capabilities!

`\"@\"` is the format string to display a cell's (text) content in quotes. There's tons of other fun stuff you can achieve. See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx).

Comment: great links daniel

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a formula -

`=CHAR(34) & A1 & CHAR(34)`

where `A1` is the cell you want to do this to. Then you can fill the series downward and cut & paste special - values back to the original location.